# How can I make this traffic light sequence repeat more than once when the button is pressed>

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById('AllButton').onclick = switchAll;

function illuminateRed() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function illuminateOrange() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function illuminateGreen() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function illuminateRedOrange() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function illuminateBlack() {
  clearLights();

}

function clearLights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

var clickTimes = 0;
var change = 1;

function switchAll() {
  clickTimes++;
  switch (clickTimes) {
    case 1:
      clearLights();
      document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
      break;
    case 2:
      clearLights();
      document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
      document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      break;
    case 3:
      clearLights();
      document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
      break;
    case 4:
      clearLights();
      document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      break;
    case 5:
      clearLights();
      document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
      break;
    case 6:
      document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
      document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
      document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
      break;

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#traffic-light {
  height: 550px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.bulb {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="AllButton" class="button">Switch</h1>
</div>
<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>
```

This is for my ICT coursework, we have to build a traffic light system and my code is working so far. However, once I press the button on the screen and each click has cycled through the possible combinations, the traffic light has finished its sequence, it won't repeat again. I am wondering if anyone could help me make it loop, I would appreciate it thanks, I am new to coding, so sorry if it is off.

Comment: So you know how to call the function that starts the cycle. have you thought of just calling the function at the end of the sequence again? By just executing `switchAll()`?

Comment: I'd suggest using an array of colours and then simply iterating through those colours in one function using a `window.setInterval()` approach. And, in all honesty, dropping JavaScript and using CSS animations instead (unless JavaScript is a requirement for some reason).

Comment: You are doing work twice! In your `switch case`es, call the functions you defined for each state. Way less code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write `clickTimes = 0;` before the last `break`.

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7oa28cta/

Comment: @ABinning Learn to accept an answer. Hover beside it to the left and you'll see a tick mark. Click it once and it will turn green. The answerer will get 15 points, you get 2. Makes people like you!

Comment: Thanks, @RachelGallen.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado no problem! :) and i'd just worked it out, so an upvote from me..

Comment: I was planning to, however it alerted me to wait a certain period of time, I have now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the background color with javascript you should change the class attribute of the element, e.g. for your element with ID "stopLight":

```
document.getElementById("stopLight").className = "blink-several-times";
```

Then use CSS animations instead of CSS transitions on the classes you set, e.g.:

```
.blink-several-times {
  animation: myAnimation linear 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: myAnimation linear 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation: myAnimation linear 4s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation: myAnimation linear 4s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation: myAnimation linear 4s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes myAnimation{
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes myAnimation{
  0% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(200px,0px)  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnimation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(200px,0px)  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes myAnimation {
  0% {
    -o-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform:  translate(200px,0px)  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes myAnimation {
  0% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(200px,0px)  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}
```

The lines with "animation-iteration-count" set the number of iterations. If it's "infinite" the animation will loop endlessly.

The many different lines -webkit, -o, -moz and so on are needed for cross-browser support.

For generating css animation code I recommend using a CSS animation generator like http://cssanimate.com/

Answer (score 1):

Short Solution

```js
var traffic_button = document.querySelector('.traffic-button');

if (traffic_button) {
  traffic_button.addEventListener('click', traffic, false);
}

var clicks = 0;

function traffic() {
  var lights = document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.lights + ' .bulb');

  if (lights.length !== clicks) {
    switch (clicks) {
      case 0:
        offLights();
        lights[clicks].classList.add('active');
        clicks++;
        break;
      case 1:
        offLights();
        lights[clicks - 1].classList.add('active');
        lights[clicks].classList.add('active');
        clicks++;
        break;
      case 2:
        offLights();
        lights[clicks].classList.add('active');
        clicks++;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  } else {
    offLights();
    clicks = 0;
  }

  function offLights() {
    for (var i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
      var element = lights[i];
      if (element.classList.contains('active')) {
        element.classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#traffic-light {
  height: 550px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.bulb {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}
.bulb.red.active {
  background: red;
}
.bulb.yellow.active {
  background: yellow;
}
.bulb.green.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="button" data-lights="#traffic-light" class="traffic-button button">Switch</h1>
</div>
<div id="traffic-light">
  <div class="bulb red"></div>
  <div class="bulb yellow"></div>
  <div class="bulb green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do this is by:

```
 case 6:
        document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
        document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
        document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
        clickTimes = 1;
        break;
```

However I would think about doing this is a more efficient way as in using a for loop to achieve this without manually clicking it each time.